What is the term for the belief that significant events cannot have trivial causes?
If Joe Shmoe falls asleep at the wheel and crashes into a tree in the middle of the night, his death is generally considered just one of those things that happen.
If the same thing happens to a famous person, a common response is to reject the explanation that it just happened and search for a more meaningful cause (or even a conspiracy theory).
Significant events feel like they must have significant causes.
What is the name for this bias or fallacy?

[philosophy.se] is the normal place to ask for the names and descriptions of fallacies.

@Barmar, yet the terminology tag lists philosophy as an example of what's suitable here.

In practice, you'll almost always get better results asking at a site dedicated to the field you're asking about. People here are generalists, not always familiar with industry jargon.

EL&U is the right place to ask this question and you rightly did so. It has the terminology tag which is commonly used, and bias/fallacy terminology questions were asked many items before. This is not really about philosophy also, it is about psychology. Philosophy SE has the terminology tag too but the questions with that tag there are usually very specific and detailed, and not usually about finding a term.

I believe proportionality bias is the right term.

The proportionality bias, also known as major event/major cause heuristic, is the tendency to assume that big events have big causes. It is a type of cognitive bias and plays an important role in people's tendency to accept conspiracy theories. Academic psychologist Rob Brotherton summarises it as "When something big happens, we tend to assume that something big must have caused it". - Wikipedia


I think this would be Argument from incredulity fallacy. It asserts that a proposition must be false because it contradicts one's personal expectations or beliefs, or is difficult to imagine.
It's sometimes also called argument from personal astonishment.
